# Calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^3}{3^x}$. What is wrong with my calculations?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

$\frac{x^3}{3^x}=\frac{\exp(3\cdot\ln(x))}{\exp(x\cdot\ln(3))}=\exp(3\ln(x)-x\ln(3))$

$3\ln(x)-x\ln(3)=\frac{9(\ln(x))^2+x^2(\ln(3))^2}{3\ln(x)+x\ln(3)}$

I will use L'Hospital

$\frac{\frac{18(\ln(x))}{x}+2(\ln(3))^2x}{\frac{3}{x}+\ln(3)}$

And this goes to infinity, for $x\rightarrow \infty$

Therefore

$3\ln(x)-x\ln(3)$ goes to $\infty$ and $\exp(3\ln(x)-x\ln(3))$ must also go to infinity

Comment: Isn't it wrong that $3\ln x - x\ln 3$ goes to $+\infty$?  It goes to $-\infty$ which means its exponential goes to $0$.

Comment: Have you tried L'Hospital right off the get go without converting to exponentials?

Comment: You can use L'Hospital rule on $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x^3}{3^x}$  3 times to get $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{6}{(ln3)^33^x}$

Comment: Setting aside the minor sign error, as pointed out in md2perpe's answer, this is an ingeniuous approach to this kind of limit. It shortcircuits multiple rounds of L'Hopital.  Did you think of it yourself? If you, good going!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect:
$$3\ln(x)-x\ln(3)=\frac{9(\ln(x))^2+x^2(\ln(3))^2}{3\ln(x)+x\ln(3)}$$

There should be a minus sign in the numerator:
$$3\ln(x)-x\ln(3)=\frac{9(\ln(x))^2-x^2(\ln(3))^2}{3\ln(x)+x\ln(3)}$$